# How to perform logical gates operation for 2 numbers in linux bash script?

Tags: bash

How to write the code to perform logical operation of given input numbers?
Whether i want to convert the given number into binary numbers and perform logical operation?

Comment: You can write code using the keyboard. StackOverflow is not designed for this kind of evasive questions. Present a specific coding  problem you have, or take a book or a tutorial to learn basis of the language
read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Post the specific problem and also what you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform logical operations between two numbers in bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
read -p "Enter 1st value:" num1
read -p "Enter 2nd value:" num2

if (($num1 && $num2))
then
echo "AND gate: 1"
else
echo "AND gate: 0"
fi

if (($num1 || $num2))
then
echo "OR gate: 1"
else
echo "OR gate: 0"
fi

if ((!$num1))
then
echo "NOT gate: 1"
else
echo "NOT gate: 0"
fi

exit 0
```